# GraphQL Filter on PageType

Tags: jss, sitecore-api, graphql

I have been successfully using GraphQL to filter on items assigned to a specific template.

Is it possible to do the same with items of a certain PageType?

Comment: What do you mean with PageType?

Answer (score 3):

There is an `includeTemplateIDs` filtering option on children:

```
topItem: item(path: $datasource) {      
     children(includeTemplateIDs: "{C6F6A81A-F9C9-45D8-AF4E-3E818C470F53}") {
       name
       url
       ... on CustomTemplate  { 
         customField { value }
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: This is very useful.. just wondering where you found this reference?  Is there some hidden JSS GraphQL documentation somewhere that I'm not aware of?

Otherwise, how would you specify more than 1 template ID to filter children on?

Comment: @Jeeby I found it in graphQL intellisense: open GraphQL browser on rendering (https://screencast.com/t/OgjG8VcxQGq), then write there "children" in query, mouse over it  (https://screencast.com/t/6ipQRf8JF) and explore on the side menu all the options (https://screencast.com/t/9V2F42a5CwbK)
However, I wasn't able to make it work for more than 1 id, despite it should be a simple array - but I didn't go further in troubleshooting, maybe it just works :)

Comment: Ah that's handy, thanks for that.  Yeah I tried a few things to get more than 1 ID to work, it wouldn't. :(